# python matplotlib - why the toolbar color produced by me is black and white?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been installing matplotlib using pip

when i was creating simple code, the appear below

[image: black and white toolbar]

I am confused because the toolbar color is black and white. If I compare the color of toolbar, see below

[image: black & white vs colorfull toolbar]

So my question is why the toolbar color produced by me is black and white?

Comment: Could you explain your question better?

Comment: question edited, done. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the toolbars from different versions of matplotlib.

- Matplotlib 2.0 has a [black&white toolbar](http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html)
               [image]
- Matplotlib <= 1.5 has [colored icons](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/users/navigation_toolbar.html) in the toolbar.
  [image]

There is no easy way to revert those icons. However, they are placed as image files in `Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images`; so an option is to replace those with other images which you like better.

Comment: Updated the answer for a possible solution without the need for downgrading (since version 2.0 provides a lot of benefits apart from the icons).